# Update per machine instance of application in multiuser enviroment

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

How installer/windows/wix handles following situation i.e. assume that more than one user is working on machine with instance of the program that was installed with option per machine. Then one of the user proceeds upgrade of applications.

How is installation proceed and how it is handled on other user profiles?
Does any additional changes in WiX project has to be made to allow installer proceed such update?

I checked that instance of the program is not closed on other user profile and user can still work with program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a per-machine product install then there is only one instance of the installed product, so any user with the appropriate privilege can choose to upgrade it when they choose. There may be multiple copies of the app running for different users but that's not relevant to the update because there is still only one product to update. The person actually doing the update owns the current desktop's interactive view, so they will see any UI notifications - the other users won't.

The behavior with multiple users depends on the MSI design and the app itself. For example, if the MSI installs one template copy of a data file that the app then copies and modifies into each user profile file location then the MSI upgrade isn't involved because it won't replace of any of those data files created by the app.

If you're referring to multiple copies of the app running, you won't see any issues if the update doesn't affect files that are in use, so yes, users can keep on working. It's dynamic and depends on the file replacement rules, if they are in use and so on.

In some cases Windows can keep an app running even though it's being uninstalled or replaced. It makes private copies of the binaries that will be removed at the next reboot or when the program finishes. It's often not predictable what will happen.

Unfortuanately your question is rather vague, so this answer may also be vague. If you have a specific scenario, and you say if your update is a patch or a major upgrade, and you explain what user profiles you're referring too then answers can be more specific.

Comment: To be more clear lets assume that we have two user log to one machine working with instance of installed product (exe file and some dlls, all data are stored in user profile). Now if one of the users decides to make upgrade to new version of exe and dlls. User that runs update will be prompt to close instance of running program by 'File in Use' dialog and update will be made immediately or at next reboot. In first case exe and dlls are overwritten on disk. Does it have any impact on the second user?

Comment: These things are not predictable - the easiest way to find out what happens in your particular case is to perform that test.

Comment: I've already run the tests and it seems that every things work correctly. Second user can work with program without distributions. But I tried to find some technical explanation that confirm my tests because at this point I have only assumption that it should work

Comment: Read my "in some cases...." paragraph. That's probably what's going on. Windows isolates the app into its own address space, makes private copies of the binary, things like that.